# Ajax call not returning any data

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to make and Ajax call  using the following code below. The same code works fine with flicker r api. but not sure why this is not working and returning any results for this url. Can someone help ?

```
var URL2='https://www.ibm.com/gateway/?&cc=br&lc=pt&format=json&ts=1340215931434&type=getExpertProfile&userid=30469&cb=200:displayData';                



$.ajax({
    url: URL2,
   // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: "callback",
    jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallbackfunction",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('on success!');
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       console.log('on error!');
       console.log("xhr.status: " + xhr.status);
       console.log("xhr.statusText: " + xhr.statusText);
       console.log("xhr.readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
       console.log("textStatus: " + textStatus);
       console.log("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
       console.log("xhr.redirect: " + xhr.redirect);
    }
});
```

Comment: you are doing a *POST* right ? maybe due to the use of `jsonp` ...

Comment: you have `url: 'URL2'` instead of `url: URL2`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'URL2',
    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    //jsonp: "callback",
    //jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallbackfunction",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('on success!');
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       console.log('on error!');
       console.log("xhr.status: " + xhr.status);
       console.log("xhr.statusText: " + xhr.statusText);
       console.log("xhr.readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
       console.log("textStatus: " + textStatus);
       console.log("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
       console.log("xhr.redirect: " + xhr.redirect);
    }
});
```

Comment: if u goes to url directly what u get?

Comment: You can't use json cross-domain. "jsonp" was the right thing to use here.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a string for your URL instead of pointing to the variable. Give bare minimum a try below.

```
$.ajax({
    url: URL2,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('on success!');
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       console.log('error');
    }
});
```

If this still fails, you should look at the network call being made and the response coming from the server. (IBM in this case) The client code here is good, but it still relies on things being set up properly on the other end. It also relies on you calling the right URL.